# Best way to determine four corners of WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got a C# MDI application where I need to determine the points for each of the four corners of the MDI Parent.  I've got four different types of Notification Child Windows that I need to display in each of the four corners.  I've tried unsuccessfully so far to get these child forms consistently and precisely positioned in the corners since screen resolution and size differ from monitor to monitor.  Part of the problem is that my application has a ToolStripMenu that runs horizontally the entire length of the Parent.

Of course the top left corner of Parent is the easiest to determine, but does any have any suggestions as to how to accurately determine the other 3 corners?

Thank you

Comment: `TOP LEFT BOTTOM RIGHT` can you calculate this based on `X,Y coordinates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the top left corner is at `(x, y)`, then:

- top right corner is at: `(x + mdiForm.Width - childForm.Width, y)`
- bottom left corner is at: `(x, y + mdiForm.Height - childForm.Height)`
- bottom right corner is at: `(x + mdiForm.Width - childForm.Width, y + mdiForm.Height - childForm.Height)`

The above coordinates are where you locate the child forms, so that they appear in the corresponding corners. You may have to add the toolbars height to the y coordinates, where applicable.

Comment: Thanks John. I used this and found that for anything on the bottom, it was displaying the child form off screen causing scroll bars. Is it calculating the Parent Height as all the way to the bottom of my screen, even though there is a clear boundary in the Parent window that stops at my start menu/taskbar? Anyone seen this happens?

Answer (score 0):

may not be correct syntax

top_right_corner.x = top_left_corner.x + form.width

bottom_left_corner.x = top_left_corner.x

bottom_right_corner.x = top_right_corner.x

top_right_corner.y = top_left_corner.y

bottom_left_corner.y = top_left_corner.y - form.height

bottom_right_corner.y = top_right_corner.y

Comment: Seems close but not quite right. I think I can make sense of it, but if you want the check and upvote, please form the answer better.